# mediaelement.js, Chrome PC, YouTube video bug, Video won't play

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, mediaelement.js

Anyone know how to fix the problem on Chrome(23.0.1271.64) PC for youtube video? When I clicked on "play".. nothing is working.

This bug is on few site that we made and I took a look on the mediaelement.js site.. [same bug](http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube). No error is shown, though.

I don't know how to fix this.. It's working on IE7+, Firefox PC & Mac, Chrome Mac.

Regards

Comment: It works quite ok for me in Chrome 23. Are you sure it's not your connection to youtube that fails?

Comment: I can double what @raina77ow said, it's working for me, on Version 23.0.1271.64 m of Google Chrome on Windows 7.